# Elastic Search query string exclude field from search scoring

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I am trying to exclude a certain field from being scored in when using Elastic Search, using the Java API.

For example, two documents:

```
{
   "id": 1,
   "bar": "foo",
   "exclude_this": "filler"
},
{
   "id": 2,
   "bar": "different",
   "exclude_this": "something else"
}
```

Currently, I am constructing the query like this:

```
    BoolQueryBuilder boolQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
    boolQueryBuilder.must(QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery(query)
        .defaultOperator(Operator.AND));
```

Where `query` is some ElasticSearch query string. Needless to say, I do not want `exclude_this` to affect search results. However, if for example `String query = "filler"`, then I don't want the object 1 showing up - in that case, I want nothing to match. I tried to use the `fields` method, which was recommended in the documentation as the way to accomplish this:

```
Map<String, Float> fieldsToQuery = new HashMap<>();
fieldsToQuery.put("bar", 1f);
BoolQueryBuilder boolQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
boolQueryBuilder.must(QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery(query)
    .defaultOperator(Operator.AND))
    .fields(fieldsToQuery);
```

However after doing this, on everything except wildcard searches, I get no results from searches; even when `String query = "foo"`, then I will get nothing, as if every field is being excluded.

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

To my opinion if I understand correct what you want, this is something you could use:

```
BoolQueryBuilder boolQueryBuilder = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
boolQueryBuilder.must(QueryBuilders
                        .multiMatchQuery("search text", "bar", "id")
                        .operator(Operator.AND)
                 );
boolQueryBuilder.mustNot(QueryBuilders
                        .matchQuery("exclude_this", "search text")
                        .operator(Operator.AND)
                 );
```